# Is self-infallibility a mental disorder?

Tags: social-psychology, personality

I realize all people have various and complex biases, and that we all get into arguments from time to time. However, I've known one or two people who seemed abnormally resistant to suggestions that they might be mistaken. Their tendancy to distrust and argue seemed to impair them socially, to the point where they struggled to maintain relationships. This makes me wonder if "self-infallability" is ever actually a mental disorder.

Is there a mental disorder associated with being severely argumentative or otherwise "self-infallible"? Especially if it impairs one's social or academic skills?

Comment: I was hoping that someone with familiarity with the DSM (Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders) could help answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not seen self-infallibility listed anywhere; however, there are a few psychological constructs that may be useful:

1. [Dark Triad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_triad)
2. [DSM5 - Conduct Disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conduct_disorder)
3. [DSM5 - Narcissistic Personality Disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_personality_disorder)
4. [DSM5 - Antisocial Personality Disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisocial_personality_disorder)

Overconfidence may be a synonym for self-infallibility in the context you are thinking.  Overconfidence would normally be thought of as a component of narcissism.

More information would probably be required to distinguish between the four identified psychological constructs but hopefully these four links are a starting point for further research.

**References**

Jones, D. N., & Paulhus, D. L. (2014). Introducing the Short Dark Triad (SD3): A Brief Measure of Dark Personality Traits. Assessment, 21(1), 28–41. https://doi.org/10.1177/1073191113514105

Answer (score 0):

["Hardening of the Smarteries"](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/ambigamy/201511/hardening-the-smarteries).

Comment: One blogger called it that. It is not a clinical term.

Comment: The referenced article was published in PsychologyToday and the author has a PhD in psychology.  The short answer is definitely too short.